# Ruby - How to set value for dynamic attribute in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, getter-setter

I have a class like this

```
class A
    #this array of attributes is dynamic, just give example for understanding easier
    attributes = ['abc','S1','S2','S3']
    attributes.each do |e|
        attr_accessor e.to_sym
    end
end
```

I want to call setter for each attribute. So, I tried this (for you understand what I want)

```
a = A.new
attributes = ['abc','S1','S2','S3']
attributes.each do |attr|
    #I know the following command is wrong (because 'attr' is not a attribute of class A)
    a.attr = 1
end
```

So, how to call setter for dynamic attribute?

P/s: using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call

```
a.send "#{attr}=", 1
a.save!
```

Comment: And make sure `attr` is not from user input, or is whitelisted, otherwise you might  run unintended methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
def set_attributes(*attributes)
    attributes.each {|attribute| self.send("#{attribute}=", 1)}
end
```